# Custom control example in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have created an attrs.xml, I tried using  `[Register("First_android.RotatedTextView")]` which gives me `noclassdeffounderror`. I tried rebuild, clean solution, deleting both obj, bin nothing.
Does anyone have a custom control example similar to this that is publicly available?

```cs
[Register("First_android.RotatedTextView")]
public class RotatedTextView : TextView
{

    public RotatedTextView(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context, null, 0)
    {

    }


    public RotatedTextView(Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {

    }

    public RotatedTextView(Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {

    }

    public RotatedTextView(Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int defStyle2) : base(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyle2)
    {

    }
}
```

My attrs.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <declare-styleable name="First_android.RotatedTextView">
       <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
 </resources>
```

Main.axml:

```xml
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:alias="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/First_android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <First_android.RotatedTextView
        android:text="Placeholder 101" />
```

UPDATE:  [AndroidJunior example not working for me](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jthhcdt9eble9u0/AndroidJunior.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `attrs.xml` is not enough, also need to parse custom properties in `RotatedTextView`.

You can do that like this:

**attrs.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="RotatedTextView">
    <attr name="customText" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**Main.axml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <AndroidJunior.RotatedTextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:customText="Test Message"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RotatedTextView.cs**:

```
namespace AndroidJunior
{
    public class RotatedTextView : View
    {
        //private int mColor = Color.Red;
        private String mText = "I am a Custom TextView sdsdasdasdsa";
        private Paint mPaint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);

        public RotatedTextView(Context context) : base(context)
        { 
        }

        public RotatedTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs,0)
        {
            TypedArray typedArray = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.RotatedTextView);
            //mColor = typedArray.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.RotatedTextView_customColor, Color.Red);
            if (typedArray.GetText(Resource.Styleable.RotatedTextView_customText) != null)
            {
                mText = typedArray.GetText(Resource.Styleable.RotatedTextView_customText).ToString();
            }
            typedArray.Recycle();
        }

        public RotatedTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        {
        }


        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);
            canvas.DrawText(mText, 100, 100, mPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Add a image to show the structure of project.

[image]

Comment: I made a new project copied your code and if the Main.axml contains AndroidJunior.RotatedTextView it just never finshes building the project. No errors just trying to deploy it, if i remove it the project builds just fine, the designer still doesn't recognizes the custom element: custom controls disabled there was an internal issue with the rendering process.

Comment: `AndroidJunior` is my tested project name, if your new project name not this, and add `AndroidJunior.RotatedTextView` to your xml will be wrong.

Comment: Yes I did named the project AndroidJunior so the namespace is correct.

Comment: Okey, you can post this demo project link, i can check it.

Comment: Here is your example https://www.dropbox.com/s/jthhcdt9eble9u0/AndroidJunior.rar?dl=0 which not working for me, thx!

Comment: The project  miss Activity's content and  `RotatedTextView` is other customed class in project.Your can create a normal new Xamarin Android project,and add `RotatedTextView` class to project.

Comment: Here is the test project.(https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohrc60jhlk34ss3/AndroidJunior.zip?dl=0).If solved problem,could you mark answer as accepted.^-^

Comment: I couldn't test your project because "Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2.1 is not compatible with monoandroid50", but I added RotatedTextView as a new class it's still not building, what Activity's content am I missing?

Comment: I found out why it didn't compiled in Tools>Extensions and updates>Mono debugging needs to be enabled. Thx you helped alot!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is, that you have to use the lower case of your namespace. Only the class name letter casing is kept.

**Solution:**

- remove the `Register` attribute
- use `<my.coolnamespace.RotatedTextView...></my.coolnamespace.RotatedTextView>`

**Example**

```cs
namespace My.CoolNamespace
{
    public class RotatedTextView : TextView
    {

        public RotatedTextView(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context, null, 0)
        { }

        public RotatedTextView(Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        { }

        public RotatedTextView(Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        { }

        public RotatedTextView(Android.Content.Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int defStyle2) : base(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyle2)
        { }
    }
}
```

```xml
<my.coolnamespace.RotatedTextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Comment: Without Register the element is invalid in source view and in designer it has grey box around it with the element name inside. It wont even compile Error: The 'first_android.RotatedTextView' is not declared. I tried deleting again obj,bin and rebuild not working.  Can you share your workng project?

Comment: `my.coolnamespace` needs to match the namespace in your .cs file. see example. I don't use the designer, but it compiles and works on the device. And keep in mind: The Designer does **not** guarantee, that custom elements are rendered correctly,because it uses an internal runtime.

Comment: It does matches the namespace. I think if you could upload a working vs project I could test it if sg is wrong my vs or I don't know.